# creating a shell script to automate csv export in mongo db

Tags: shell, ubuntu, csv, mongodb

We have mongo db and in that we have a list of collections which i wanna export to csv using the mongoexport tool. I need to do this often and the names of the collections changes sometimes. So what i wanna do is create a shell script that i can just run and it will iterate over the collections in the mongo db and create csv files. Right now i have a script but its not automated for example i have the following in a script.

```
 mongoexport -d mydbname -c mycollname.asdno3rnknlasfkn.collection --csv -f field1,field2,field3,field4 -o mycollname.asdno3rnknlasfkn.collection.csv
```

In this all the elements will remain same except csv filename and the collection name where both are same.

So i wanna create a script which will

```
 show collections
```

then loop over the collection names retrieved and replace it in the export tool command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call "show collections" through mongo from the shell.
I suggest you write a small skript/program using your favorite language
fetching the collection names through the driver's API and then execute
mongoexport through your script/program using a system call (system()).

Comment: I did something similar. I made a .js file fetching all the collections and made a shell script to catch its output and generate the export commands

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done via the shell - don't know if the comments above refer to old versions of the mongo shell...
Example:

```
echo 'show collections' | mongo dbname --quiet
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#############################################################
Script 1 -- to produce a list of databases in MongoDB server
#############################################################

#!/bin/bash
####################################################################
# PROGRAM:      mongolistdbs.sh
#
# PROGRAMMER:   REDACTED
# PURPOSE:      Program created to list databases in Mongo
#               
# CREATED:      02/14/2011
#
# MODIFCATIONS:
###################################################################
#set -x
#supply mongo connection parms: server and port 
mongo localhost:12345 --quiet <<!!  2>&1
show dbs
!!


########################################################
Script 2 -- This is the driver that calls script 1
#########################################################
####################################################################
# PROGRAM:      mongodb_backup_driver.sh
#
# PROGRAMMER:   REDACTED
# PURPOSE:      Program created to drive the MongoDB full database
#               backups
# CREATED:      02/14/2011
#
# MODIFCATIONS:
###################################################################

#!/bin/bash


        ################################################
        # backup strategy is individual backup
        # of all databases via loop and db list
        # (dbparm is empty string)
        ###############################################
        echo "Strategy: All via Individual Loop"

        ####################################
        ### here is the call of script 1
        ####################################
        DBs=`./mongolistdbs.sh | cut -f1 | egrep -v ">"`
        for db in $DBs;
        do
                echo  "Driver loop for backup of [ ${db} ]"
                #############################################################
                ### here im calling my backup script (not supplied) 
                ### with database as a parameter within a loop
                ### to backup all databases individually
                #############################################################  
                ./royall_mongodb_backup.sh ${db}
        done
```